# Didn't Get the updated value in data source.read function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My problem is that I'm setting the value in the `filterA` function on change event but when I call `this.datasource.read()` in the `filterB` function i don't get the updated value. My code so far:

```
function FilterA(element) {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: '@Url.Action("Filter_A")'
            }
        },
        change: function (e) {
            var index = 1;
            var temp = "";
            $(".k-input").each(function () {
                if (index === 3) {
                    temp = $(this).text();

                }
                index++;
            });
            index = 1;

            $('#hdntemp').val(temp);
        },
        optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
    });

}

function FilterB(element) {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: '@Url.Action("Filter_B")' + "?temp=" + $('#hdntemp').val()
            }
        },
        open: function (e) {
            this.dataSource.read();
        },
        optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution 
save the datasource element somewhere globally in oncreate function and call the function in onchange funciton to get cascading effect.